# Can I use a single app secret to create multiple oauth2 tokens and send emails from Gmail?

Tags: c#, email, google-api, google-oauth

We have a desktop application that needs to send emails on behalf of our clients (institutions), to our client's clients (real people).

After investigating about creating an intermediate web service that will hold our secret key, and retrieve oauth2 tokens on demand from the desktop app, then the desktop app uses that token to make google api calls to send emails.

I've come to the [bulk mail guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/bulk-mail)
and I'm afraid the mails would get marked as spam (as they will have different senders)

We need to make something like thunderbird but only for sending notification mails.

Is there any other way to do this? How so?

Comment: MailGun, SendGrid, and other email SaaS offerings are probably more in line with what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gmail for this is **NOT** going to go well.

Instead, as you are working on behalf of institutions you will do better to pick one of two options:

1. Require your clients to provide credentials for their own smtp servers as part of the setup process for the application.
2. Run your own smtp server (which is *NOT* trivial, but still doable) and require your clients to include your server's address in the appropriate places in their DNS so your server shows as legitimate sender for their domain.

As the main systems administrator at a small college, I've had to do both kinds of setup for various applications.

If you go option 2, get a real server with a real IP. I've had application vendors request to add SPF records for whole AWS ranges, and I am **NOT** going to approve that.